# Replicaset or Deployment with multiple template specifications

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to create a replicaset / deployment with multiple template specifications - say I had one template specification for logical group "app = ui, rel = stable" and other template specification for "app = as, rel =stable".

Is it possible to create a replicset / deployment targeting "rel=stable" - to target all the pods with the label "rel = stable" ?

Please see the attached pic for more details

Credits : Kubernetes In action

[image]

**Update1** - adding more details. I am aware of deployments to some extent. However, wanted to know if this is possible ? If not , how can achieve it.
The requirement is to have a single deployment that manages different types of pods.

Please see yaml file for reference. Please ignore images names and ports etc., those are just some dummy names

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: nginx-deployment
      labels:
        rel: stable
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          rel: stable
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            rel: stable
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: uipod
            image: ui
            ports:
            - containerPort: 80
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            rel: stable
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: aspod
            image: as
            ports:
            - containerPort: 81
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            rel: stable
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: pcpod
            image: pc
            ports:
            - containerPort: 82
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            rel: stable
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: scpod
            image: sc
            ports:
            - containerPort: 83
```

Comment: What do you mean by targeting?

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing?
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I think you have a misconception about `ReplicaSet`s. Each deployment may have mutliple `ReplicaSet`s (one for each version). Thus, if we have two deployments (`"app = frontend"` and `"app = db"`), we have two separate `ReplicaSet`s

Comment: I don'ti f I get your question. But you can use HELM to create deployment templates. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Ok , I am aware of how deployment works and it seems deployment allows to manage one pod specification. However, say as per the fig, Is it possible to create a deployment that manages all the templates ( Pods ) that had the label " rel = stable"

Answer (score 0):

> "manages all the templates ( Pods ) that had the label " rel = stable""

I don't exactly what you mean with, but it not possible create a deployment to manage other deployments.

You can create a deployment file with as many pods you want, but if to separate them you need to use external script/kubectl command to manage all of them.